# MariaDB (MySQL) slow query when primary key range combined with fulltext index

Tags: mysql, query-performance, index-tuning, full-text-search

I've a table described below, with two columns - integer primary key and title text - currently holding circa 3 million records. As seen in the metadata below, there's a BTREE index on integer primary key column, and FULLTEXT index on title column.

```
MariaDB [ttsdata]> describe records;
+------------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------------------+-------------------------------+
| Field            | Type                | Null | Key | Default             | Extra                         |
+------------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------------------+-------------------------------+
| id               | int(15) unsigned    | NO   | PRI | NULL                | auto_increment                |
| title            | varchar(2000)       | YES  | MUL |                     |                               |
+------------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------------------+-------------------------------+

MariaDB [ttsada]> show index from records;
+---------+------------+-------------------------+--------------+------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table   | Non_unique | Key_name                | Seq_in_index | Column_name      | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+---------+------------+-------------------------+--------------+------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| records |          0 | PRIMARY                 |            1 | id               | A         |     2798873 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| records |          1 | title                   |            1 | title            | NULL      |           1 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | FULLTEXT   |         |               |
+---------+------------+-------------------------+--------------+------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
```

I'd like to run the following query:

```sql
SELECT * FROM records
WHERE
  id > 2589968 AND
  MATCH (title) AGAINST ('+flower' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
LIMIT 200
```

This query takes more 5 seconds to execute. When I remove the the range part or the fulltext part, in both cases the query executes in circa 100 ms. Below is analysis of individual queries, the last one being the one I want to use.

So my question is: How can I make the query fast?

Below I've posted statistics for each separate condition and for combined conditions. Each statistics contains:

- `EXPLAIN`
- Execution time with `SQL_NO_CACHE`
- Number of matched rows

I'm new to MySQL and DBA in general. I don't know how to draw any conclusions from it.

The `2589968` magic number is something that just happens to be needed.

#### Query 1

```sql
SELECT * FROM records
WHERE id > 2589968
LIMIT 200
```

```
MariaDB [ttsdata]> explain SELECT * FROM records WHERE id > 2589968 LIMIT 200;
+------+-------------+---------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+--------+-----------------------+
| id   | select_type | table   | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref  | rows   | Extra                 |
+------+-------------+---------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+--------+-----------------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | records | range | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 4       | NULL | 227183 | Using index condition |
+------+-------------+---------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+--------+-----------------------+
1 row in set (0.005 sec)

MariaDB [ttsdata]> SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE * FROM records WHERE id > 2589968 LIMIT 200;
...
200 rows in set (0.108 sec)

MariaDB [ttsdata]> SELECT count(*) FROM records WHERE id > 2589968;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|   208905 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.257 sec)
```

Query time: **0.108 sec**

#### Query 2

```sql
SELECT * FROM records
WHERE MATCH (title) AGAINST ('+flower' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
LIMIT 200
```

```
MariaDB [ttsdata]> explain SELECT * FROM records WHERE MATCH (title) AGAINST ('+flower' IN BOOLEAN MODE) LIMIT 200;
+------+-------------+---------+----------+---------------+-------+---------+------+------+-------------+
| id   | select_type | table   | type     | possible_keys | key   | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra       |
+------+-------------+---------+----------+---------------+-------+---------+------+------+-------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | records | fulltext | title         | title | 0       |      | 1    | Using where |
+------+-------------+---------+----------+---------------+-------+---------+------+------+-------------+
1 row in set (0.007 sec)

MariaDB [ttsdata]> SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE * FROM records WHERE MATCH (title) AGAINST ('+flower' IN BOOLEAN MODE) LIMIT 200;
...
200 rows in set (0.138 sec)

MariaDB [ttsdata]> SELECT count(*) FROM records WHERE MATCH (title) AGAINST ('+flower' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|  1846710 |
+----------+
1 row in set (6.056 sec)
```

Query time: **0.138 sec**

#### Query 3

```sql
SELECT * FROM records
WHERE
  id > 2589968 AND
  MATCH (title) AGAINST ('+flower' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
LIMIT 200
```

```
MariaDB [ttsdata]> explain SELECT * FROM records WHERE id > 2589968 AND MATCH (title) AGAINST ('+flower' IN BOOLEAN MODE) LIMIT 200;
+------+-------------+---------+----------+---------------+-------+---------+------+------+-------------+
| id   | select_type | table   | type     | possible_keys | key   | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra       |
+------+-------------+---------+----------+---------------+-------+---------+------+------+-------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | records | fulltext | PRIMARY,title | title | 0       |      | 1    | Using where |
+------+-------------+---------+----------+---------------+-------+---------+------+------+-------------+
1 row in set (0.005 sec)

MariaDB [ttsdata]> SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE * FROM records WHERE id > 2589968 AND MATCH (title) AGAINST ('+flower' IN BOOLEAN MODE) LIMIT 200;
...
200 rows in set (5.627 sec)

MariaDB [ttsdata]> SELECT count(*) FROM records WHERE id > 2589968 AND MATCH (title) AGAINST ('+flower' IN BOOLEAN MODE) LIMIT 200;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|    91026 |
+----------+
1 row in set (6.817 sec)
```

Query time: **5.627 sec**

### Analyze statement on the queries

```sql
WHERE id > 2589968
```

```
MariaDB [ttsdata]> analyze SELECT * FROM records WHERE id > 2589968 LIMIT 200;
+------+-------------+---------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+--------+--------+----------+------------+--------------------------+
| id   | select_type | table   | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref  | rows   | r_rows | filtered | r_filtered | Extra                    |
+------+-------------+---------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+--------+--------+----------+------------+--------------------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | records | range | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 4       | NULL | 227210 | 200.00 |   100.00 |     100.00 | Using where; Using index |
+------+-------------+---------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+--------+--------+----------+------------+--------------------------+
1 row in set (0.007 sec)
```

```sql
MATCH (title) AGAINST ('+flower' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

```
MariaDB [ttsdata]> analyze SELECT * FROM records WHERE MATCH (title) AGAINST ('+flower' IN BOOLEAN MODE) LIMIT 200;
+------+-------------+---------+----------+---------------+-----------+---------+------+------+--------+----------+------------+-------------+
| id   | select_type | table   | type     | possible_keys | key       | key_len | ref  | rows | r_rows | filtered | r_filtered | Extra       |
+------+-------------+---------+----------+---------------+-----------+---------+------+------+--------+----------+------------+-------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | records | fulltext | title         | title     | 0       |      | 1    | 200.00 |   100.00 |     100.00 | Using where |
+------+-------------+---------+----------+---------------+-----------+---------+------+------+--------+----------+------------+-------------+
1 row in set (0.007 sec)
```

```sql
WHERE id > 2589968 AND
MATCH (title) AGAINST ('+flower' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

```
MariaDB [ttsdata]> analyze SELECT id FROM records WHERE id > 2589968 AND MATCH (title) AGAINST ('+flower' IN BOOLEAN MODE) LIMIT 200;
+------+-------------+---------+----------+---------------+-------+---------+------+------+------------+----------+------------+-------------+
| id   | select_type | table   | type     | possible_keys | key   | key_len | ref  | rows | r_rows     | filtered | r_filtered | Extra       |
+------+-------------+---------+----------+---------------+-------+---------+------+------+------------+----------+------------+-------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | records | fulltext | PRIMARY,title | title | 0       |      | 1    | 1755861.00 |     8.12 |       0.01 | Using where |
+------+-------------+---------+----------+---------------+-------+---------+------+------+------------+----------+------------+-------------+
1 row in set (5.768 sec)
```

### EXPLAIN and ANALYZE with index hints

#### No index hint

Query:

```sql
SELECT * FROM records
WHERE
  ID > 2589968
  AND MATCH (title) AGAINST ('+flower' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
LIMIT 200
```

The same results are reported for `USE INDEX (PRIMARY, title)` index hint.

Result:

```
MariaDB [ttsdata]> explain SELECT * FROM records WHERE ID > 2589968 AND MATCH (title) AGAINST ('+flower' IN BOOLEAN MODE) LIMIT 200;
+------+-------------+---------+----------+---------------+-----------+---------+------+------+-------------+
| id   | select_type | table   | type     | possible_keys | key       | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra       |
+------+-------------+---------+----------+---------------+-----------+---------+------+------+-------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | records | fulltext | PRIMARY,title | title     | 0       |      | 1    | Using where |
+------+-------------+---------+----------+---------------+-----------+---------+------+------+-------------+
1 row in set (0.009 sec)

MariaDB [ttsdata]> analyze SELECT * FROM records WHERE ID > 2589968 AND MATCH (title) AGAINST ('+flower' IN BOOLEAN MODE) LIMIT 200;
+------+-------------+---------+----------+---------------+-------+---------+------+------+------------+----------+------------+-------------+
| id   | select_type | table   | type     | possible_keys | key   | key_len | ref  | rows | r_rows     | filtered | r_filtered | Extra       |
+------+-------------+---------+----------+---------------+-------+---------+------+------+------------+----------+------------+-------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | records | fulltext | PRIMARY,title | title | 0       |      | 1    | 1755861.00 |     8.12 |       0.01 | Using where |
+------+-------------+---------+----------+---------------+-------+---------+------+------+------------+----------+------------+-------------+
1 row in set (5.763 sec)
```

#### USE INDEX(PRIMARY)

Query:

```sql
SELECT * FROM records USE INDEX (PRIMARY)
WHERE
  ID > 2589968
  AND MATCH (title) AGAINST ('+flower' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
LIMIT 200
```

Results:

```
MariaDB [ttsdata]> explain SELECT * FROM records USE INDEX (PRIMARY) WHERE ID > 2589968 AND MATCH (title) AGAINST ('+flower' IN BOOLEAN MODE) LIMIT 200;
+------+-------------+---------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+--------+------------------------------------+
| id   | select_type | table   | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref  | rows   | Extra                              |
+------+-------------+---------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+--------+------------------------------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | records | range | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 4       | NULL | 227210 | Using index condition; Using where |
+------+-------------+---------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+--------+------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.006 sec)

MariaDB [ttsdata]> analyze SELECT * FROM records USE INDEX (PRIMARY) WHERE ID > 2589968 AND MATCH (title) AGAINST ('+flower' IN BOOLEAN MODE) LIMIT 200;
+------+-------------+---------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+--------+--------+----------+------------+------------------------------------+
| id   | select_type | table   | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref  | rows   | r_rows | filtered | r_filtered | Extra                              |
+------+-------------+---------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+--------+--------+----------+------------+------------------------------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | records | range | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 4       | NULL | 227210 | 930.00 |   100.00 |      21.51 | Using index condition; Using where |
+------+-------------+---------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+--------+--------+----------+------------+------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.014 sec)
```

Comment: did you try to add hint to use primary key?

Comment: @NikitaSerbskiy You may be onto something! I've modified the query with `USE INDEX (PRIMARY)` and it was fast! I've also tried `USE INDEX (PRIMARY, title)` and it was slow. :-) Both queries returned _correct_ results, but different subsets (with `LIMIT 200`). I'm currently busy with other things but I'll return to this and update question later. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have:

- 208905 rows WHERE id > 2589968
- 1846710 WHERE MATCH (title) AGAINST ('+flower' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
- 91026 WHERE id > 2589968 AND MATCH (title) AGAINST ('+flower' IN BOOLEAN MODE)

It means ~43% of rows with id > 2589968 contain 'flower' in their title.

For some reason query optimizer decides to use fulltext index to start. Since fulltext index doesn't contain id column server needs to perform a lot of lookups to the table to check id condition. Only ~5% of rows are matched the id condition and I suppose most of them are located "at the end" of fulltext index because you are looking for those ones which were added later (id column is auto_increment). So server performs a lot of unsuccessful lookups and for your conditions it would be faster just to start reading of your clustered index (which is primary key) from id > 2589968 and check each record for fulltext condition (4 of 10 should give the successful result) and finish after 200 matches.

What also you can try to do to make performance better?
Rebuild your table using column FTS_DOC_ID BIGINT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY instead of id. This is built-in MySQL name for column which should contain document id used as reference in fulltext index. I'm not sure if it will work the same way in MariaDB and actually I didn't test it with MySQL but it may help server to avoid a lot of extra lookups.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed analysis. Could you please expand a bit on _it would be faster just to start reading of your clustered index_? Is it forced by index hint, in my case `USE INDEX (PRIMARY)`? Because I've just checked the results with this index hint, and they are all correct and the query is executed fast. I've updated the question with index hint EXPLAIN & ANALYZE.

Comment: I'm just reading about your suggestion at https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-fulltext-index.html#innodb-fulltext-index-docid. I haven't tried it yet, but I fear that changing PK column name may not be desirable as this identifier is hard-coded on many places. I think I'd rather try to add non-PK `FTS_DOC_ID` column and set it to the same value as new row's `id` value in `BEFORE INSERT` trigger.

Comment: @woky yes, reading the clustered index is forced by use index hint. Also index hints don't affect the query results, of course if your indexes are not corrupted :) They may affect only execution plan.

Comment: @woky - Please let us know if you succeed in making `FTS_DOC_ID` into the PK.

Comment: I think the bottom line is that FT is not designed to be efficient when it returns 91K rows.

Answer (score 0):

Since neither part of the `WHERE` clause will help much in filtering, and since there is no practical way to combine them into a single index, I see little hope for fast.  But here is another thing to try:

```
SELECT * FROM records
WHERE MATCH (title) AGAINST ('+flower' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
HAVING ID > 2589968
LIMIT 200
```

(I don't know if the Optimizer will try to be too smart and move the `HAVING` into the `WHERE`.)

Be aware that a `LIMIT` without and `ORDER BY` will deliver an unpredictable subset of the rows.

Comment: Good point about limit without order by, with order by id it may even choose to use clustered index without hint.

Comment: @NikitaSerbskiy - That's because it can do both the ID>... and ORDER BY with the aid of the index (that is, the PRIMARY KEY).